# Weird error with py2exe and Sympy

Tags: python, error-handling, py2exe, importerror, sympy

Ok, I am making a program using SymPy. I use sympy.Eq, sympy.solve, and sympy.Symbol. When I compile my program and I run the command (It's a User Interface) that uses sympy.solve, sympy.Eq, and sympy.Symbol. It works perfectly when it is not compiled, but when I compile it with py2exe (as a bundled executable), it gives my this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RateTime.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "RateTime.py", line 33, in main
  File "RateTime.py", line 4, in get_catch_up_time
  File "sympy\solvers\solvers.pyc", line 883, in solve
  File "sympy\solvers\solvers.pyc", line 316, in check_assumptions
  File "sympy\assumptions\ask.pyc", line 88, in ask
  File "sympy\assumptions\assume.pyc", line 94, in _eval_ask
  File "sympy\assumptions\assume.pyc", line 157, in eval
  File "sympy\utilities\source.pyc", line 26, in get_class
ImportError: No module named handlers
```

I tried changing the code in source.py from

```
lookup_view = getattr(__import__(mod_name, {}, {}, ['*']), func_name)
```

to

```
exec "import "+mod_name+" as MODULE"
lookup_view = getattr(MODULE, func_name)
```

And it gave me the error even when the project WASN'T compiled. I assume a python file in sympy is not being included because it is not normally imported immediatly. I had to change it back. Is there a way to fix this? I really need my python project to be distributed as a executable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the ImportError does indeed mean that py2exe didn't pick up sympy.assumptions.handlers nor its submodules. The easiest workaround is probably to add

```
import sympy.assumptions.handlers.calculus
```

right where you import sympy.

You may need to do the same for "order", "sets" and "ntheory" in addition to "calculus".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing the sympy code, I suppose you could add those files to the relevant `__init__.py` files, so that they are imported when sympy is.